# html5 volume slider go to 200%

Tags: slider, html5-video, volume, decibel

I'm looking for a way to increase the volume past 100%. I have some videos where the volume in html5 maxed to 100% is kinda low. Is there anything to make the max volume 200% or define the decibel level that 100% is?

Answer (score 4):

It is true that you cannot set the actual volume property of a video tag nor an audio tag above 1, but you can use the Web Audio API to the volume to be twice as loud as normal, effectively doubling the volume:

```js
function amplifyMedia(mediaElem, multiplier) {
  var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext),
      result = {
        context: context,
        source: context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElem),
        gain: context.createGain(),
        media: mediaElem,
        amplify: function(multiplier) { result.gain.gain.value = multiplier; },
        getAmpLevel: function() { return result.gain.gain.value; }
      };
  result.source.connect(result.gain);
  result.gain.connect(context.destination);
  result.amplify(multiplier);
  return result;
}
```

The function should be pretty easy to use but this page also gives more details:
http://cwestblog.com/2017/08/17/html5-getting-more-volume-from-the-web-audio-api/

Answer (score 0):

A html5 video's volume property can only be set from 0 to 1 (i.e., 0 to 100 percent):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Setting outside that range will throw an error. For example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].volume = 2;
```

results in

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (2) is outside the range [0, 1].
```

Comment: I understand that part. When I play the video in WMP for example the sound at 50% is nice and clear. When I play it on a web page at the same 50% the audio is hard to hear. At 100% I can hear it but barely. That is with volume on laptop full blast and speakers set full. I was hoping there was a way to define the volume level of 100%. A code for setting decibels for the volume for example. 100% of of 70db is 70. 100% of 80db is 80.